# Scroll to a specific position jquery SlimScroll

Tags: angular, slimscroll

I have two portions in page one is scrolling and second is not scrollable. when I click on left side question this question display in the right side.

I used slimScroll so my question is how to scroll specific question to specific position programmatically.

Also, I have attached image please refer it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-io-slimscroll

> My app design image

[image: My app design image]

Answer (score 1):

slimscroll provides the `scrollTo` option to set specific point where to start from scrolling.

Example:

```
scrollTo = "100"
```

The above code start scroller from top 100px. So when you select a question from left side you need to set `scrollTo` each time programatically.